# css hover over a div and another div changes opacity

Tags: css, hover, transparency

I'm trying to use CSS in my WordPress site to change the opacity of a div column on the hover of adjacent div column.

This is the CSS I'm using but it's not working. I want to hover over the dog box and have the cat box change to half transparency.

```css
.dog_box {
    height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float:left;
}

.cat_box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

.dog_box:hover .cat_box{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="dog_box"></div><div class="cat_box"></div>
```

This is my site link. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
https://parapetcarestg.wpenginepowered.com/home2/

Comment: We need a [mcve] which in this case would also include your relevant HTML. Also note that your CSS is attempting to select elements with the class of cat_box that are **descendants** of elements with the class dog_box, not siblings of. `~` and `+` are sibling selectors

Comment: Your selector assumes that cat_box is a child of dog_box which it is not. It's a sibling. You need something like `.dog_box:hover + .cat_box`

Comment: okay i've created a basic html/css version of my issue. How would i create this so that they are descendants of the same class?

Comment: wow thank you it's working now! I knew I was missing something simple. thanks a bunch

Comment: If the + works for an adjacent sibling what can i use if I want to also do the reverse and have .cat_box:hover + .dog_box. Is there a different way of doing it. I tried ~ but it didn't work unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else was searching for the previous sibling css this worked (I think it might not be supported by firefox though)

```css
.dog_box:hover + .cat_box {
    opacity: 0.7;
}


.dog_box:has(~ .cat_box:hover){
    opacity: 0.7;
}


.dog_box {
    height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float:left;
}

.cat_box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="dog_box"></div><div class="cat_box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your selector is searching for a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). You want to use a sibling selector like `~` ([general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator)) or `+` ([adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator))

```css
.dog_box {
    height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float:left;
}

.cat_box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

.dog_box:hover + .cat_box{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="dog_box"></div><div class="cat_box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The current code, changes the opacity of all `cat_box` elements inside the `dog_box`.

In this example you want to use the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator) (`~`) to change the css of all `cat_box` elements that are at the same level as the `dog_box`, but appear later on the page.

```
.dog_box:hover ~.cat_box{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: If the ~ works for an adjacent sibling what can i use if I want to also do the reverse and have .cat_box:hover ~ .dog_box. Is there previous sibling selector?